# Finding the cardinality of $\{X\in \mathcal P(\mathbb R)| |X|=\aleph_0 \}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

> Let $S$ be a relation over $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$ such that $A,B\subseteq\mathbb R: \exists f:A\to B, \exists g: B\to A$ and $f,g$ are injections.
>
> Find the cardinality of $\{X\in \mathcal P(\mathbb R)| XS\mathbb Z\}$.

We should note that $S$ is an equivalence relation and from CSB we know that $|A|=|B|$ so we can write the above set like so: $\{X\in \mathcal P(\mathbb R)| |X|=\aleph_0 \}$, from here I think this set is isomorphic to an infinite union of countable sets and we know that this is countable, but, it also represent $\mathcal P (\mathbb Q)$ because all the subsets of the reals that are countable are all the reals apart from the transcendental numbers. Probably the latter line of thinking is correct.

I should use the injections in order to prove the cardinality is $\mathfrak c$ but I can't seem to make sense of it.

Comment: If your set (which I'll call $A$) is countable, then $\mathbb{R}$ is countable, because any element of $\mathbb{R}$ is in some element of $A$. So $A$ is definitely uncountable. 

It also has cardinality at least continuum, which you can prove as follows. Let $\mathbb{I}$ denote the irrational numbers, and consider $f : \mathbb{I} \to A$ defined by $f(x) = \mathbb{Q} \cup \{ x \}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Cantor-Bernstein theorem. Then you first have to prove that there are *at least* $\mathfrak c$ countably infinite subsets of $\mathbb R$, and then that there *at most* $\mathfrak c$ of them.

The first one is easy -- the sets $\mathbb{Z}\cup\{x\}$ for $x\in(0,1)$ are $\mathfrak c$ different countably infinite subsets.

For the second one, you need a uniform, injective way to code each countable subset of the reals as a real. If you have the Axiom of Choice you can do that by showing that every *sequence* of reals can be encoded as a single real (which is a simple exercise in using the equalities $|\mathbb R|=|\mathcal P(\mathbb N)|$ and $|\mathbb N|=|\mathbb N^2|$).

I don't think the conclusion is necessarily true *without* Choice.

Comment: "I don't think the conclusion is necessarily true *without* Choice." It is not. It is a theorem of Tarski that (provably in $\mathsf{ZF}$) for any set $X$, the collection of well-orderable subsets of $X$ always has size strictly larger than $X$. And it is consistent (with dependent choice) that the only well-orderable subsets of $\mathbb R$ are the countable ones. Since we can prove directly that there are $|\mathbb R|$ finite subsets, it follows that in this setting, the collection of countably infinite subsets of $\mathbb R$ has size strictly larger than $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Andres: Tarski? Not Sierpinski?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Alfred Tarski, [*On well-ordered subsets of any set*](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm32/fm32115.pdf). Fund. Math., **32**, (1939), 176-183.

Comment: @Andres: Oh, thanks!